# Pass KeyDown event to other control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, keydown

I am writing a C# WinForms application, .NET 4.0.

I have a WinForms `Control` on a `Form`. After user starts typing something using keyboard, another `Control` appears. That `Control` is some kind of text input. I'd like to send user input to that `Control`. Of course, after it gets focused, it receives all user keyboard input. But as user starts typing before `Control` appears, I have to pass first `KeyDown` event to that control after I call it's `Show` and `Focus` methods.

[SendKeys.Send method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a way of doing something similar. But that is so complicated, and seems to be unsafe. I have just a value of `Keys` enumeration from `KeyData` property of `KeyEventArgs`, I'd like to use it, not transform it to some strange string.

Is there any good way to pass `KeyDown` event from one control to another?

Comment: Calling `SendMessage` via P/Invoke should work.

Comment: Try looking at the [KeyPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of your form.

Comment: For generic solution (listening to keyboard input of any control of the form) `Form.KeyPreview` is the best. Other possible solution is to route event (every control what can have keyboard input will have to subscribe to **same** event, which pass data to `Control`) or implementing keyboard hook (to catch keyboard input from other applications).

Comment: This is expected, by the time you get the KeyDown event, the keystroke (and above all, the KeyPress) is already committed to the control that had the focus when you pressed the key.  A workaround would be to have the KeyPress event handler of the one control set the Text property of the other.  Do keep in mind that this is not a very intuitive user interface.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason you can't just pass the event onto the "child control" ? Below example is KeyPress but the same idea applies for KeyDown

```
//Parent Control Visible
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1_KeyPress(sender, e);
}
//Child Control Hidden
private void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.Text += e.KeyChar.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I'd not like to change `Text` by myself. User might press Backspace, Delete, Home or End button. Also, a part of text might be selected.

Comment: This seems to be a reasonable solution though. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `PreviewKeyDown` on `Form`.

Suppose you want to send keyboard inputs to `TextBox textBox1`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.PreviewKeyDown+= Form1_OnPreviewKeyDown;
        textBox1.Visible = false;
    }

    private bool _textboxEnable = false;
    private void Form1_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs previewKeyDownEventArgs)
    {
        if (!_textboxEnable) textBox1.Visible = true;
        if (!textBox1.Focused) textBox1.Focus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom control which inherites the a textbox. YOu can place that custom control instead. In that custom control you can write a method  which calls it:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public void TriggerKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        this.OnKeyPress(e);
    }
}
```

If you dont want to make use of custom controlls you can make an extension to a textbox and use reflection to call it:

```
public static class TextBoxExtensions{
    public static void TriggerKeyPress(this TextBox textbox, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        MethodInfo dynMethod = textbox.GetType().GetMethod("OnKeyPress", 
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        dynMethod.Invoke(textbox, new object[]{ e });
    }
}
```

But with both methods you should know: This will not add the text from one object to another. To do that you will have to write that in your code manually.

Comment: The problem is that my control is complex `UserControl`, which contains `ElementHost` and WPF control inside. WPF control is a kind of `TextBox`, but more complex.