# Invoke event from unknown control

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I'd like to invoke an event from unknown control in code.
I'd love to do the following, but the "KeyDown" property is only for adding or removing (+= -=) events, not for invoking...

```
private void QBDT_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Control l_oActiveControl = this.ActiveControl;
    if (l_oActiveControl is TextBox)
    {
        TextBox l_tbActive = l_oActiveControl as TextBox;
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C || e.KeyCode == Keys.Z || e.KeyCode == Keys.X || e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        {
            l_oActiveControl.KeyDown(sender, e); 
            return;
        }
    }
    //Do Something
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks :)

Comment: Why are you trying to send the event to the control? are you just trying to send only those letters to the text box? it might be easier to just append the text to the textbox instead of trying to forward a event like that.

Comment: Check out these questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27507946/pass-keydown-event-to-other-control https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841178/how-to-call-an-event-manually-in-c